# Can voltage and current be stepped up and connected together

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Ok if a boost convertor is used to step up voltage, then a seperate buck convertor is used to step down, increasing the current, can these two be configured to utilize the high voltage on one output, then utilize the high current on the other output and connect the both together

Comment: No you cannot boost power this way. You only get out a % of what you put in, so the transformer impedance ratios always apply ignoring start surges or pulse currents.

Comment: Yes, you can cascade multiple DC-DC converters. This is sometimes useful, but not generally the best option.

Comment: you could do that ..... i bet that the resulting fireworks would be magnificent

Answer (score 2):

No, absolutely not. The output of the buck converter is at a lower voltage than the output of the boost converter. Connecting a high voltage, low-current source to a low-voltage source will cause current to flow **into** the low voltage source, which is just the opposite of what you propose.

Energy must be conserved. If you use a dc-dc converter to get a higher voltage then you must have a reduced current. If you use a dc-dc converter to increase the current then you must have a reduced voltage. As a wise man once said, TNSTAAFL.

Comment: What if diodes were added to stop the flow of current to the output with lower current so only the high current flows

Comment: Well then you wouldn't get any of the low-voltage current. It would be just as if there was no low-voltage, high-current supply. What would be the point of that?

Comment: To increase power, using the high voltage  from one output and the high current  from the other output.

Comment: @AndrewHernandezHernandez You can't get around conservation of energy. Seriously, don't break the laws of physics; physics has _very_ good lawyers.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "utilize".  Beyond that whole second law of thermodynamics thing, each converter will be in the 75% - 90% efficient range.  If each is 80% efficient, then for every 100 W into the first converter you will get only 64 W out of the second converter.  Sketch a basic wiring diagram of what you want to try, write in some input voltages and currents, and see what the outputs are.

Answer (score 1):

The [Law of Conservation of Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy) says (in one form) that whatever you do, you can't get more energy out of a system than you put in,

Laws sometimes get a bad rap, keep off the grass, don't drive faster than 70, but this one is not of that type. It's a description of what happens. Since scientists noticed this behaviour, they've done all sorts of careful experiments, and it's never been found to be wrong, ever.

It's rather nice to have this as a law, as a general principle, because if something appears to violate it, you don't need to flog through all the details, you just know that it's wrong.

If you said I have a black box, which takes a 10W input and delivers a 20W output continuously, then you just know it cannot happen. No conceivable arrangement of converters can do this.

Energy can be stored. The black box could have a battery, capacitor or inductor in it. It could take 10W while charging, then discharge to deliver pulses of 20W, or yet shorter pulses of 100W. Increasing the the power output while reducing the output time is a perfectly respectable activity.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked of me, in high-school. The person planned to use a vacuum tube with 2 cathodes and a single plate, to combine the high current and the high voltage.

I did not know how to explain the conflict, other than "energy is not free."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it won’t give you the result you’re asking. You need to look at the wattage of the power supply, not the current or voltage. They are always tied together so just voltage or just current doesn’t tell you enough.

For example, you can take a power supply, let’s say 100W, and boost it to 100V, but the current will be limited to 1A. Or you can take that same 100W power supply and buck down to 1V and the current limit will be 100A.

Now, let’s say you attach both a buck and boost converter. Using some sort of isolation, like transformers, you could combine the two power supplies to get 100V+1V=101V. However, the combined converters will only allow 100W/101V=0.99A.  If you tried to pull more current, the voltage would begin to drop because the power supply just can’t supply enough energy to sustain 101V at a current greater than 0.99A.